# How can I input audio?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, torch

> TL;DR: I have combined 1,000 `mp3` files into one large `mp3` file, but am unable to pass this file through the Torch framework.

I have been able to use Torch to successfully generate unique output from Shakespeare samples. Now, I want to take this a step further and input an audio file instead of a text file.

```
bash$ audio.load(/path/to/fullyMerged.mp3)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/path/to/fullyMerged.mp3'
```

I tried using audio.load(path) as suggested on torch documentation [here](https://github.com/soumith/lua---audio/), but I get an unexpected token error.

> Edit: Here are some things I have tried, but failed

- Tried inputting mp3 directly using, however, mp3 is an invalid input: `python scripts/preprocess.py --input_mp3 data/fullyMerged.mp3 --output_h5 data/fullyMerged.h5 --output_json data/fullyMerged.json`
- Tried renaming the `.mp3` extension to `.txt` and feeding it into Torch, however, that returns a [UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040196/how-can-i-represent-audio-in-text-without-unicodedecodeerror), since audio cannot be represented as text
- Tried converting my `.mp3` file into `.raw` format, `.wav` format, and many others, however, no audio format was processable by Torch.
- Also tried renaming the extensions of these converted `.raw` and `.wav` files into `.txt`, but that still gave me a [UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040196/how-can-i-represent-audio-in-text-without-unicodedecodeerror)

I've spent countless hours trying to get Torch to process audio, but am unable to do so! Any feedback at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the combined mp3 file playable using a normal mp3 player ?  possibly file is corrupt

Comment: @ScottStensland The file is playable and is definitely not corrupt. Is it possible that I forgot a command to load the mp3 file or something?

Comment: another approach would be to convert each mp3 into .wav  then pluck out the payload from the wav ( ignore the header bytes in front ) then combine all the payloads into one .wav ... assure its playable then convert it into mp3 ...  does torch have a mp3 decoder ?    removing the .wav header leave the payload as a time series curve in PCM format perhaps Torch can handle the data as PCM better than as mp3

Comment: @ScottStensland I was able to take your advice and turn my file into PCM, but I don't know how to turn that back into text

Comment: The fact that this simple question went unanswered for two days should work as a very effective and drastic illustration of why [not to post code or error messages as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

`audio.load` is not a valid Bash command. The error message is slightly confusing because the parentheses are invalid, too; and trigger a parsing error even before Bash tries to execute anything at all.

To start an interactive Python session, type `python` at the Bash prompt. You'll still need to `import` something before Python, either, accepts `audio.load` as a function name.

Perhaps you should spend some time familiarizing yourself with Python before attempting to use it for nontrivial new development efforts.

... Except it looks like the library you are linking to is a Lua library, not a Python library. I have no familiarity with Lua but the rest of this answer still stands. Probably start with the usage example near the end of [the Lua-Audio project's `README`](https://github.com/soumith/lua---audio/blob/master/README.md) and copy/paste it into a text file, then figure out how to run that with Lua.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a string to `audio.load` instead of `/Users/.../fullyMerged.mp3`

You should replace

```
audio.load(/Users/.../fullyMerged.mp3)
```

with

```
audio.load('/Users/.../fullyMerged.mp3')
```

Comment: This, too, once you get so far as to actually be running Python.

Comment: ... Wait, not Python; Lua!?

Comment: If he run lua command from bash, it will surely not work...

Comment: Quite so; the image he posted showed that the error message came from Bash, though it's extremely unclear how he later on managed to run Python on something and get a UnicodeDecodeError somehow.